# Where to define routes in Ember CLI?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I've created some routes using `ember generate route {my_route_name}` and it creates a js file under routes and a hbs file under templates

Now I want to define these routes like

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
});
```

But where do I do that in `ember-cli`?

I've tried adding it in the `app.js` file right under this code

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: 'front', // TODO: loaded via config
    Resolver: Resolver
});
```

But that gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

So I am a little confused as to where to actually define all my routes?

Comment: Which version of ember-cli?

Comment: It was v0.0.39 but I didn't realize there was a router file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be defined in the `app/router.js` file.

Since you used `ember generate route` it's likely that a route is already defined there for you, you'll just need to update it.